# Having trouble re-sizing JButton in Java

Tags: java, swing, resize, jbutton, layout-manager

Whenever I add my jbutton to my container it's really huge. I thought using the label.setBounds() function would work but it didn't

```
public Liability_Calculator(String s)
{
    super(s);
    setSize(325,200);
    Color customColor = Color.WHITE;

    c = getContentPane();
    c.setLayout(new BorderLayout());


    //the button
    ok = new JButton("OK");

    //ok.setSize(50, 50);

    //HERE IS WHERE I TRY AND RESIZE!
    ok.setBounds(30,30,50,50);

    c.add(ok, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestions:

- You will want to read up on the [layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/) to
- understand why your GUI is behaving this way
- and to see how to use the layout managers to your advantage to create better looking GUI's in an easy way.
- You'll also want to avoid setting bounds on any gui components.

For instance, a JPanel uses `FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER))` by default, and you can use that to your advantage by placing your ok JButton into a JPanel and then the JPanel into the contentPane:

```
  ok = new JButton("OK");
  // ok.setBounds(30, 30, 50, 50);

  JPanel southPanel = new JPanel();
  southPanel.add(ok);

  c.add(southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

This will change the first image to the second:

[image]  [image]